# sysbench on Raspberry Pi

Tags: benchmarking, raspberry-pi4, disk-io, sysbench

I am trying to use sysbench on Raspberry Pi 4(8GB RAM).

What I'm trying to compare is the **difference in** **disk I/O** **between native and kvm guest VMs**.

From some papers, it is generally said that native and docker have the best performance and VM has the lower performance. However, in my environment, native and docker came out significantly lower than guest VM.

Is there any reason(options or execution path, ...) for this wrong result?

I allocate 4 cores, 4GB RAM to guest VM.

Followings are what I used to test.

`sysbench --test=fileio --file-total-size=5G prepare`

`sysbench fileio --num-threads=2 --file-total-size=5G --max-time=60 --max-requests=0 --file-extra-flags=direct --file-test-mode=seqrd --file-block-size=512 run`

I executed this commands at the root directory(/)

And `df -h` result.

[image: Result of df]